# How to send an E-Mail inside of an app in Xcode?

Tags: ios, email, send

I am new to xcode, and am wondering how to send email in an app! My code is below, but I keep getting the error "No visible @interface for 'jakem' declares the selector 'presentViewControllerAnimated:'". Is my code completely wrong? Or did I just forget to declare the selector, and how do I declare the selector? I have researched all over the internet for at least an hour, and nothing is working. Someone please help me!

```
    -(IBAction)sendEmail{

    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray          arrayWithObjects:@"FrankMurphy.CEO@RomansXIII.com", nil]];
    [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES];

    }

    }

    -(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller   didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    if(error) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error" message:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"error %@", [error description]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

in .h header file....

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>



@interface SimpleEmailViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> // Add the delegate
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender;



@end
```

in .m implementation file.....

```
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender {
// Email Subject
NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
// Email Content
NSString *messageBody = @"iOS programming is so fun!";
// To address
NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"info@finetechnosoft.in"];

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
[mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

// Present mail view controller on screen
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}




- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{



switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}


// Close the Mail Interface
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.
You do this like

```
@interface YouClassName : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> 

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! And yes I did that in my header file

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong method. Try

```
[self presentViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL) completion:(void)completion];
```

instead of:

```
[self presentViewController:composer animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

I work for Sendgrid. We have an Objective-c library that lets you quickly send email from inside your app, https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-objc. You can use cocoapods to quickly install the library in your project.

Then sending the email from your (IBAction) would look like this:

```
-(IBAction)sendEmail{

sendgrid *msg = [sendgrid user:@"username" andPass:@"password"];
msg.to = @"FrankMurphy.CEO@RomansXIII.com";
msg.from = @"me@bar.com";
msg.text = @"hello world";   
msg.html = @"<h1>hello world!</h1>";

[msg sendWithWeb];

}
```